# join value FormData with axios use javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, multipartform-data

i send value using postman with body form data format like this :

[example with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvdvK.jpg)

```
analisa_type:1;1;2
eficiency_type:0;1;1
```

I input array data with separator (;)

i am confused how to separate it on axios
this is my code

```
 items_efiicieny: [{
          id_analisa_exception: '',
          analisa_exception_label: '',
 }],


let eficiency_name = this.items_efiicieny.map(x => x.id_analisa_exception).join(";");
let eficiency_type = this.items_efiicieny.map(x => x.analisa_exception_label).join(";");

const f = new FormData();
f.append("analisa_type", eficiency_name);
f.append("label_type", eficiency_type);
```

how to format the form data so that the value is like in postman?

Comment: Your example should work, is there any error in console ?

Comment: looks like I have to ask the backend, thanks